# Why am I getting a NullPointerException when I return mocked values?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a class:

```
public CustomerService Implements custStruct {

    public Service changeCustomer(Guest guest) {
    ...

    Seats seat = custService.assignSeats(tickets);

    if(!seat.full) { // <--- this line is giving Null Pointer (seat is null)
     ...do something
    }
   }
```

My test is written like this:

```
// ...
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        customerService = new CustomerService();
        customerService = Mockito.spy(customerService);
    }
// ...
@Test
public void testAssignSeats(){
    Guest guest = Mockito.mock(Guest.class);
    Seat seat = Mockito.mock(SeatCalc.class);
    Tickets tickets = Mockito.mock(Tickets.class);
    CustService custService = Mockito.mock(CustService.class);

    customerService.set(tickets); //tickets is a setter
    customerService.set(custService); //set to use another class's method
    Mockito.when(custService.assignSeats(tickets)).thenReturn(seat);

// ...
    customerService.changeCustomer(guest);
}
```

I was wondering if there are a way to stub values on the `if` statement? and if I tried to stub `seat` how will it work?

Edit: added more information on Seat Class
below is the Seat class...

```
public class Seat{
    public boolean full= false;
    public SeatArrangeRequest seatArrangeReq;
    public List<ArrangeOrder> arrangeOrderList;
}
```

Here is the custService method called from...

```
public seats custService(Tickets tickets) {

if(tickets!= null) {
    ...do some algorithm...
    return seats
}

    seat.full = true;
    return seat;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a problem because customerService is sometimes identified as "custService" or is this a typo in the code presented?

Comment: Not typo customerService is the class name for CustomerService and
 CustService is a different class...

Comment: I don't believe that seat is null in the line indicated; I believe that seat.full is null.  I'm not sure how to mock a field like full; it is probably better practice to use (and mock) a getter method, in this case, isFull().

Comment: I debugged it and the variable seat showed as null in the debugging variable state...

Comment: [sorry for the extended discussion] Then you are not successfully mocking custService; we don't see enough of your code to know what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

One of two things is going on, I'm not entirely certain your MCVE matches your real code. It's either one of:

1. You are trying to access an instance field of a mock object. Instead, use a real object (if `Seat` is just a [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object)), or define a getter that you can mock (`seat.isFull()`).
2. The `tickets` in your test don't match the `tickets` object you're using in `CustomerService`. You can fix this problem by using an [Argument Matcher](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#3), which will match **any** `Tickets` object, e.g.

   ```
   customerService.set(tickets); //tickets is a setter
   customerService.set(custService); //set to use another class's 
   methodMockito.when(custService.assignSeats(Mockito.any(Tickets.class))).thenReturn(seat);
   ```

If neither of these fixes your problem, then please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32189260/edit) your question to more accurately reflect what you're really doing.

Comment: I have added more information about the class/method do you see anything that I might missed?